# User code type with device code flow and Openiddict

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openiddict

I am using OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore version *4.0.0* to facilitate device flow authorization. Grant type is set to *urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code* and I am getting following response:

```
{
    "device_code": "eyJhbGciOiJSU0EtT0FFUCIsImVuYyI6IkEyNTZDQ..",
    "expires_in": 599,
    "user_code": "eyJhbGciOiJSU0EtT0FFUCIsImVuYyI6IkEyNTZDQk...",
    "verification_uri": "https://localhost:3000/verify",
    "verification_uri_complete": "https://localhost:3000/verify?user_code=eyJhbGciOiJSU0EtT0FFUCIsImVuYyI6IkEyNTZDQk..."
}
```

The user code is a JWT token instead of a short string. Is it possible to configure the user code type somehow?

Thank you,
Ondrej

Program.cs:

```
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();
    services.AddSingleton<IPrincipalProvider, LocalPrincipalProvider>();
}
else
{
    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options => builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
    services.AddSingleton<IPrincipalProvider, AADPrincipalProvider>();
}

services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddServer(options =>
    {
        options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/authorize")
               .SetTokenEndpointUris("/token")
               .SetLogoutEndpointUris("/logout")
               .SetDeviceEndpointUris("/device")
               .SetVerificationEndpointUris("/verify");

        options.AllowDeviceCodeFlow();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that degraded mode was enabled using options.EnableDegradedMode(). Possible solutions include disabling degraded mode or implementing your own exchange of JWT codes for short strings.